# How to turn convert one character column into multiple numerical columns in R

Tags: r

I want to a character column into multiple numerical columns.

For example, I have these columns in table "final":

final

| sd2 | file |
| --- | --- |
| 0.011 | r100.0.8.1.1.csv |
| 0.023 | r10.0.2.0.1.csv |
| 0.033 | r10.0.95.0.0.csv |

I want to turn it into something like below. The "file" column is separated into 3 separate columns where there is no longer an "r" or ".csv" and the first two numbers (ie  100 and 0.8) are in different columns but the last one (ie 1.1) remain in one column- although this could be further separated into two columns if easier (ie the 1 and 1 in the "dom" column could be in separate columns).

| sd2 | pop | sel | dom |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.011 | 100 | 0.8 | 1.1 |
| 0.023 | 10 | 0.2 | 0.1 |
| 0.033 | 10 | 0.95 | 0.0 |

I've used strsplit to make the "file" column a list of character strings.

```
files <- final$file
files <- as.character(files)

per <- strsplit(files, "[.]")
```

I'm not sure how to turn these strings into separated columns, while forgoing the "r" and ".col" Any suggestions on next steps would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option with `read.csv` from `base R`.  Here, we can capture the substring as a group, modify the delimiter with `,`, and use `read.csv` to read the column as a `data.frame` and assign new columns to 'final' dataset in `base R`

```
final[c("pop", "sel", "dom")] <-  read.csv(text = 
  sub("^[a-z](\\d+)\\.(\\d+\\.\\d+)\\.([0-9.]+)\\.csv",
       "\\1,\\2,\\3", final$file), header = FALSE)
```

---

The same option can be used in `extract` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
final %>%
    extract(file, into = c("pop", "sel", "dom"),
         "^[a-z](\\d+)\\.(\\d+\\.\\d+)\\.([0-9.]+)\\.csv", convert = TRUE)
```

-output

```
#    sd2 pop  sel dom
#1 0.011 100 0.80 1.1
#2 0.023  10 0.20 0.1
#3 0.033  10 0.95 0.0
```

#### data

```
final <- structure(list(sd2 = c(0.011, 0.023, 0.033), file = c("r100.0.8.1.1.csv", 
"r10.0.2.0.1.csv", "r10.0.95.0.0.csv")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 1):

An option is to `strsplit` at letters or point, make a matrix out of non-empty elements whose interrelated columns we `paste` together with `"."`.

```
u <- unlist(strsplit(d$file, "[a-z]|\\."))
u <- matrix(u[nchar(u) > 0],,5,b=T)
res <- data.frame(sd2=d$sd2, sapply(list(pop=1, sel=2:3, dom=4:5), function(x) 
  as.double(apply(u[, x, drop=F], 1, paste, collapse="."))))
res
#     sd2 pop  sel dom
# 1 0.011 100 0.80 1.1
# 2 0.023  10 0.20 0.1
# 3 0.033  10 0.95 0.0
```

---

*Data:*

```
d <- structure(list(sd2 = c(0.011, 0.023, 0.033), file = c("r100.0.8.1.1.csv", 
"r10.0.2.0.1.csv", "r10.0.95.0.0.csv")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```